# How to I restore original select option values in select box while doing multipage Search

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a JSP Page 1, In this JSP Page I have one lets say link1.When I click on that Link, it goes to JSP 2.Now in JSP 2, I have 4 include jspf pages.Header/footer/search box /main content page.Now in in this Search box jspf page, I have search page html code in which I have select fields where in the user selects one option while doing search.Now when I do multiple pages search for the same option value field,its not maintaining its value across the search pages.I need to maintain that value for same user session ,How do I implement this ?

Some of the things I tried, for search page,I stored the value of select box in session and then in jspf page, I tried retreiving it via jstl something like this.,

```
<

select name="Name" class="cl-search" id="id-search"  lang="en">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${ empty sessionScope.TEST1}">
                                <option id="bt" value="test1">TEST1</option>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <option id="bt" value="test1"><c:out value="${sessionScope.TEST1}"/></option>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose> 
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${ empty sessionScope.TEST2}">
                                <option id="gt" value="test2">TEST2</option>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <option id="gt" value="test2"><c:out value="${sessionScope.TEST2}"/></option>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose> 
                         <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${ empty sessionScope.TEST3}">
                              <option id="tod" value="test3">TEST3</option>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <option id="gt" value="test3"><c:out value="${sessionScope.TEST3}"/></option>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

in servlet I have something like this,

```
String selectvalue = request.getParameter("selectname");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(selectvalue.equals("test1")){
            session.setAttribute("TEST1",test1);
        }else if(selectvalue.equals("test2")){
             session.setAttribute("TEST2",test2);
        }else if(selectvalue.equals("TEST3")){
            session.setAttribute("TEST3",test3);
        }
```

Not sure if I have explained my problems correctly,all I want it that if users select one value from select box and does the search and if search results spans multiple pages,how do I maintain the same select value across all the pages for that category for that session of the user.I have close to 10 values in select field,depending on this value is it calls different classes of the DAO.

Comment: Anyone please.I am open for all suggestions.

Comment: Ok I resolved this with standard HTML using selected markup.